# Could not connect to mysql database in kubernates with spring boot app

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and Docker.
I have a simple spring boot app which uses MySql database.

Following is application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://webapp-mysql:3306/bootdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Temp@1234
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Following is the pods.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: webapp
  labels:
    app: webapp
    release: "06"
spec:
  containers:
    - name: webapp
      image: andy999/shareserviceproj:release06

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  containers:
   - name: mysql
     image: mysql:8
     env:
      # Use secret in real life
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: Temp@1234
      - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
        value: bootdb
```

Following is the Services.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: share-webapp

spec:
  selector:
    app: webapp

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30080

  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-mysql

spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql

  ports:
   - port: 3306
  type: ClusterIP
```

But all the time I am getting following error, the problem is my web app could not connect to the database, I tried all the connection strings in app.prop without port with port, all are failing with same error.
In addition to that I can not figure out the post URL to be use from postman to POST the data.

> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:829)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:449)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:242)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
> at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)

Comment: Please check this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2985169/16923081)

Comment: My sql pod is starting correctly......... do not understand why my webapp can not connect to it.......